# Controller requires a value for one parameter - Internal server error 500

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, symfony

Does implementing of AJAX with Symfony2 is so difficult as I see it now?

My goal is to implement a one-page application that displays a form for creating posts (each post has a post title and a post content). When the form is submitted, AJAX takes in charge displaying the post below the form in the div#output.

My template looks like:

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}

    <form action="{{ path('post_creates', { 'id': entity.id }) }}" id="form_ajax" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
        <p>
           <input type="submit" value="create" />
        </p>
    </form>

        <ul class="record_actions">
    <li>
        <a href="{{ path('post') }}">
            Back to the list
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div id="output"></div>

{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jwpsrv.com/library/leLjogZ6EeOBvCIACusDuQ.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('bundles/testblog/js/test2.js') }}"></script>

    <script>

$("#form_ajax").submit(function(){ 


    tinyMCE.get("test_bundle_blogbundle_posttype_postContent").save();

    var content= $("#test_bundle_blogbundle_posttype_postContent").val();

    var title  = $("#test_bundle_blogbundle_posttype_postTitle").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "{{ path('post_creates', { 'id': entity.id }) }}",
        data: {datas:title, date:content},
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){

           $('#output').html(data);

        }
    });    
    return false;
});
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

The controller is:

```
public function createsAction(Request $request, $id)
    {

     $request = $this->container->get('request');

     $entity  = new Post();

    if($request->isXmlHttpRequest())
    {
       $title = $request->request->get('datas');
       $content = $request->request->get('date');

        $em = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();

        if($title != '')
        { 


        $entity->setPostContent($content);

        $entity->setPostTitle($title);
        $id=$entity->getId();

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();


            $post = $em->getRepository('TESTBlogBundle:Post')->find($id);
        }
        else {

            $post = $em->getRepository('TESTBlogBundle:Post')->find($id);
        }

         $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);


    return $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse('TESTBlogBundle:Post:show.html.twig', array(
            'entity' => $post, 'id' => $id,
             'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),  
            ));
    }
    else {
        return $this->indexAction();
    }

    }
```

I have a the following problem:

```
Controller requires that you provide a value for the "$id" argument (because there is no default value or because there is a non optional argument after this one).
```

When I var_dump the $id inside my controller, I always have null. My controller works fine if I pass a value to it in function arguments. My knowledge in Symfony2 doesnt allow me to find what I am missing. Your help is really appreciated.

Comment: In the rendered HTML, what is the value after `url:` in your ajax call?

Comment: @cheesemacfly, thank you for your feedback. the value is /site/web/app_dev.php/post/creates. I see no id, even when I pass a value to $id in controller arguments function.

Comment: What if you dump your entity in your twig template: `{{ dump(entity) }}`. Does it have an id?

Comment: @cheesemacfly, in `show.html.twig`, the entity is dumped only when I pass a value in controller arguments, and it is containg the id. I really dont understand it is been 2 days where the problem comes from.

Comment: You have a problem in your controller then. Make sure you send a valid entity to the view in your action.

Comment: @cheesemacfly, I think the controller is never executed if I dont fix a value for $id in arguments. when I var_dump $entity, I get nothing. Please to correct me, thanks.

Comment: What I meant is you should look at the controller rendering your view in the first place (the one containing the ajax call) because this is the one missing the entity.

Comment: Thank you very much @cheesemacfly for your time. You were pointing the  right problem. Can you please send a small answer so that I can upvote?

Comment: The answer below already contains the solution and your problem has been solved. That's what counts :)

Comment: Thank you very much. I hope I can me too help one day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the returned error message.

The url you're calling through Ajax didn't contain any value for the `$id`.

As `$id` is required according to your action definition. You've to be sure it's always provided.

**Update:**

When you run the `action` that display the `template` for the first time (It may be the same action or another one), it's providing a non-valid `entity` (which doesn't contain any `id`). So, when it builds the `url` you're using in you `ajax call`, it calls an url that doesn't contain any `id`.

**Edit by OP:**

The parameter `$id` of the `$entity` is not defined till you persist data into database. So remove it from the arguments of the controller, and remove it also from the template by removing the `entity.id`

Comment: I beleive that you are pointing the right issue, but really I dont understand you 100 percent. Thanks for your time

Comment: Make sure your $entity variable has an id. dump it on your controller or inside your twig template.

Comment: I think $entity has the variable $id, since when I pass a random value to $id in contoller arguments, it works fine. (`public function createsAction(Request $request, $id=55)`).

Comment: I see. The controller is responsible of building the entity with random protected id, and before triggering the controller, I declare in template entity.id, which is not yet defined. I need to find a way to define my id before executing my action.Thanks

Comment: I found the solution, which is based on your expnanations , you and cheesemacfly. I will give it as an edit to your answer. Many thanks.

Comment: It was rejected by other reviewer I think. Wait, I'm looking for it to add it to the answer.